# Save file which is opened using iFrame

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, dialog

I am opening the contents using iFrame as a pdf file. When I click the link download. In IE browser, it is asking me to save or open. But in Firefox browser, it is straight away opening the pdf in a dialog box. I want the FF browser to do the same behavior as IE does. How to do ?

Comment: This is not a programming question but I think you want to look at: Tools->Options->Applications and then see what Firefox is associating PDF documents with.

Comment: Also you can serve the pdf as application/octet-stream if you want to force the download dialog

Comment: @thatidiotguy how about for Chrome browser ?

Comment: @mplungjan. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: @thatidiotguy. I have a question here. I have installed the Firefox browser just now. So when I clicked that link, aint it suppose to ask the Open or Save ? Is there anyway we can force in the code to open this dialog box ?

Comment: If you open a pd from the server, the mime type is likely application/pdf - this will trigger whatever the browser is set to do - in your case open in browser for Fx and prompt in IE. If your server sets the mime type to `application/octet-stream` all browsers will prompt

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. I am checking your ans now

Comment: in FF, you can always fetch the PDF with ajax and use window/data URL with an <a download> tag/attrib set to force a named-file download action instead of a navigation.

Comment: @mplungjan. No :( . Its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a REALLY simple way for FF + chrome that doesn't even need JS:

```
<a download="mypdf.pdf" href="/res/docs/pdf/chapter5.pdf" > Download PDF </a>
```

Comment: Actually its more like different. Onclick of the save button I am using a JS to create an iframe

Comment: Actually now it is working in IE and Firefox browser. But fails in Chrome

Comment: var getStudentFile = document.createElement(""iframe""); window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('getStudentFile').src=XXXXX

Comment: @Cyril:  You've called the html initiator a link, and a button, and referred in passing to an iframe. i'm confused as to what's actually going on. post your current code and we can fix it as the download attrib should work in chrome.

Comment: Hi. I cannot post the entire code as it is very huge. And moreover , I don't have to download the file in Chrome browser. I want to display the Open/Save dialog in Chrome browser. Do you know how ?

Comment: @cyril: chrome just downloads what it wants, unlike firefox which offers the open/save box...